# url regex issues

Tags: regex, url

I'm using this regex `(((ht|f)tp(s?))\://)?(www.|[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|edu|gov|mil|net|org|biz|info|name|museum|us|ca|uk)(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\;\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*` to search for urls, the only problem, is it's finding "you ca" is a url, how do I change it so there HAS to be a period before the ending (in this case the 'ca') so 'you ca' wont work anymore but 'you.ca' will

Comment: I can see you have unescaped . in your regex, try to escape them and check if it works.

Comment: If you a tell us your target language, there may be a library we can suggest to you instead of trying to write a complex parser in regex

Comment: Can we **please** stop trying to “validate” URLs by checking their TLD against known values? Do you really want to have to update your expression every time ICANN approve a new TLD? Do you really think that's even all the TLDs that exist at the moment? (hint: no.)

Comment: @bobince I understand that, but name one other, easier way in AS3 to do that

Comment: Allow any series of `.`-separated alphanumerics/`-` as a hostname. Don't try to arbitrarily restrict what TLDs are allowed. If you are searching text for URLs you should generally not mark up bare domain names without `http://` as being URLs (they're not, and almost anything is a valid hostname). At a pinch you may be able to get away with `www.`-prefixed hostnames only.

Answer (score 3):

Parsing uris with regexes is a hard problem.

Either use a library like [Regexp::Common::URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp::Common::URI) or prepare to spend lots of time investigating a bunch of RFCs. Parsing URIs is entirely not trivial and there are lots of subtle mistakes to be made.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to escape the periods in the (www.|[a-zA-Z].) block.

Comment: How does that have anything to do with the `\.` block before the `(com|edu...` block?

Comment: I dont know much about regexes, how would I escape them?

Comment: Add a \ before the periods in that block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quantifier for the period character, so '\.{1}' would require exactly one period before whatever follows.

It's not something that's a necessary part of the debugging of this problem, but it may help to know about it. It's just more explicit, and '{1}' is bigger than a dot, so it also serves as a separator in long, ugly regexes where, during debugging, you might accidentally throw a "+" or "*" next to the dot.

Comment: How is that different from '\.'?

Comment: +1 for discovering not one, but two uses for `{1}`. :D  I still can't see myself ever using it, though; the clutter it adds to the regex cancels out whatever benefit it brings, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I use a freeware to check my regex:
http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/

perhaps it can be helpfull to you

Answer (score 0):

John Gruber's regexp is the best so far in my experience at finding URLs. See his article on his blog: [An Improved Liberal, Accurate Regex Pattern for Matching URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls). It's in use in lots of production code. There's two version: one matches any URL while another only matches http/https URLs.